# Internet Explorer 11 renders page strangely until reszing?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Just started testing IE11 with our internal websites and found this error occurs (see link below) but if you resize the window it renders the page correctly. Only happens on some pages and I can't see why? Has anyone seen this before?

http://i151.photobucket.com/albums/s135/tonyyeb/ie11error_zps83d87df7.png

**EDIT:** Just to clarify the page when rendered correctly looks NOTHING like this!

**EDIT2:** We think it maybe showing the page at a VERY high zoom level.

Comment: Are there any errors or messages appearing in the developer tools console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem, jQuery was being included twice in the page causing this random event to occur.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have code that is specific to different browsers?
If so then note that the User-Agent string of IE11 is very different than the user-agent strings of the past IEs and usually parsing scripts of this user-agent work in a weird way.
I would guess that because of this new string some parsing of it fails which causes the javascript on the page to stop (as JavaScript does on errors) and then work again on a resize because you have some action done on resizing.

Comment: No there isn't anything specific to browsers. The page renders correctly sometimes and if refreshed but others it renders like shown. It must be an IE bug as it doesn't do it all the time.

Comment: sounds like it, most of the issues in IE11 I've noticed come from the user-agent issue. Do you have any javascript errors on the page?